# How to establish a Putty Serial connection through a Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, putty

From a Python script, I would like to start PUTTY for  a serial line (COM1, COM2,.. etc) and also mention the speed through python script.

I have explored, but most of the information is helpful for Python to Putty (SSH) connection.

Will it be possible to establish Python to Putty(Serial) connection and take logs?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to communicate over serial link, consider using
[`PySerial`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial/), I used it many times for communicating with devices connected via serial link and it works very well on MS Windows as well as on Linux.

Putty is just a type of console, which allows to communicate with serial link, but for your Python it is not required.